# How to make memcached laravel into stateless?

Tags: php, laravel, caching, memcached, stateless

I'm working with a memcached version of Laravel... memcache was added by a previous developer despite instructions for things to be stateless. In trying to remove memcache, I either cause php to fail horribly, or I later discover that, somehow, caching remains.

How can I remove caching from laravel?

Comment: Can you be more specific please. What errors are you getting? What have tried?

Comment: I get a huge stack trace of laravel/illuminate that leads deep into the cacheing code stack, and if I alter slightly the stack changes. If I had removed caching properly, it shouldn't be going into those errors. So it's not so much the specific errors so much as "what's the proper way to do this?"

As for what I have tried, gone into app/config and pretty much commented out everything in regards to caching.